# Unable to initialize the route param when I open the app directly from another webpage in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am new to angualr 7 , I am trying to build a dashboard for users and users will get url for their dashboard from email .

*Example :*

> Dear User,
>
> Please open the portal using this link (hyperlink to localhost:4200/dashboard/myuserid)

I am trying to achieve this by using angular router and path parameters

***AppRoutingModule.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "dashboard/:id",
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
```

I am able to read the path variable using ActivatedRoute in ngOnInit  like this

```
ngOnInit() {
      let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  }
```

I am getting the below error when I try to access the page by using hyper link in the mail

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dahboard/B50A43A6EE303E9D239A1F62956B8F2D'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1384)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1365)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
```

But when I hard code the parameter in one of the components I am able to open the dashboard without any issues

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'B50A43A6EE303E9D239A1F62956B8F2D']"  
        >Dashboard</a
      >
```

Any Ideas what could be causing this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dahboard is not the same as dashboard :), so I guess you should fix your link in your email to have 'dashboard' in it.

If you want a 404 page on an unknown path, you should add the following as the **last** item of your app routing:

```
{
  path: '**',
  component: Error404Component
}
```

Comment: Yes In deed , the link that is present in the mail was wrong .Is there any way to show a error page / component when path does not match instead of showing blank component ?

Comment: @nsivaram90 I've updated my answer to answer your question